# Python: Convert tuples from re.findall into string?

Tags: python, regex, printing, proximity

I wish to read in a text, use regex to find all instances of a pattern, then print the matching strings. If I use the re.search() method, I can successfully grab and print the first instance of the desired pattern:

```
import re

text = "Cello is a yellow parakeet who sings with Lillian. Toby is a clown who doesn't sing. Willy is a Wonka. Cello is a yellow Lillian."

match = re.search(r'(cello|Cello)(\W{1,80}\w{1,60}){0,9}\W{0,20}(lillian|Lillian)', text)
print match.group()
```

Unfortunately, the re.search() method only finds the first instance of the desired pattern, so I substituted re.findall():

```
import re

text = "Cello is a yellow parakeet who sings with Lillian. Toby is a clown who doesn't sing. Willy is a Wonka. Cello is a yellow Lillian."

match = re.findall(r'(cello|Cello)(\W{1,80}\w{1,60}){0,9}\W{0,20}(lillian|Lillian)', text)
print match
```

This routine finds both instances of the target pattern in the sample text, but I can't find a way to print the sentences in which the patterns occur. The print function of this latter bit of code yields: ('Cello', ' with', 'Lillian'), ('Cello', ' yellow', 'Lillian'), instead of the output I desire: 
"Cello is a yellow parakeet who sings with Lillian. 
Cello is a yellow Lillian."

Is there a way to modify the second bit of code so as to obtain this desired output? I would be most grateful for any advice any can lend on this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just make a big capturing group around the two endpoints:

```
import re

text = "Cello is a yellow parakeet who sings with Lillian. Toby is a clown who doesn't sing. Willy is a Wonka. Cello is a yellow Lillian."

for match in re.findall(r'(Cello(?:\W{1,80}\w{1,60}){0,9}\W{0,20}Lillian)', text, flags=re.I):
    print match
```

Now, you get the two sentences:

```
Cello is a yellow parakeet who sings with Lillian
Cello is a yellow Lillian
```

Some tips:

- `flags=re.I` makes the regex case-insensitive, so `Cello` matches both `cello` and `Cello`.
- `(?:foo)` is just like `(foo)`, except that the captured text won't appear as a match. It's useful for grouping things without making them match.

Comment: Thank you! A simple solution indeed!

Answer (score 3):

## Description

Use a forward lookahead like in this regex which will capture complete sentences which contain both Cello and Lillian.

`(?:(?<=\.)\s+|^)((?=(?:(?!\.(?:\s|$)).)*?\b[Cc]ello(?=\s|\.|$))(?=(?:(?!\.(?:\s|$)).)*?\b[Ll]illian(?=\s|\.|$)).*?\.(?=\s|$))`

[image]

The expression is broken down like to these functional components:

- `(?:(?<=\.)\s+|^)` start matching this sentence at after a `.` followed by any number of spaces or at the start to of the string
- `(` start capture group 1 which will capture the this entire sentence
- `(?=` start the look ahead

  - `(?:(?!\.(?:\s|$)).)*?` ensure the regex engine doesn't leave this sentence by forcing it acknowledge a `.` followed by either white space or an end of string
  - `\b` matcht the word break
  - `[Cc]ello` match the desired text either all lower case or with a capital initial
  - `(?=\s|\.|$)` look ahead to ensure the string has a trailing space, `.`, or the end of the string
  - `)` end of the look ahead
- `(?=(?:(?!\.(?:\s|$)).)*?\b[Ll]illian(?=\s|\.|$))` this essentially does the same but for Lillian
- `.*?\.(?=\s|$)` capture the rest of the sentence upto and including the period, and make sure the period is followed by either white space or the end of the string
- `)` end of the sentence capture group 1

## Code example

I don't know python well enough so I offer a PHP example. Note in match statement I'm using the `s` option which allows the `.` expression to match new line characters

Input text

```
Cello is a yellow parakeet who sings with Lillian. Toby is a clown who doesn't sing. Willy is a Wonka. Cello is a yellow Lillian.
Cello likes Lillian and kittens.
Lillian likes Cello and dogs.  Cello has no friends. And Lillian also hasn't met anyone.
```

Code

```
<?php
$sourcestring="your source string";
preg_match_all('/(?:(?<=\.)\s+|^)((?=(?:(?!\.(?:\s|$)).)*?\b[Cc]ello(?=\s|\.|$))(?=(?:(?!\.(?:\s|$)).)*?\b[Ll]illian(?=\s|\.|$)).*?\.(?=\s|$))/s',$sourcestring,$matches);
echo "<pre>".print_r($matches,true);
?>
```

Matches

```
$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cello is a yellow parakeet who sings with Lillian.
            [1] =>  Cello is a yellow Lillian.
            [2] => 
Cello likes Lillian and kittens.
            [3] => 
Lillian likes Cello and dogs.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Cello is a yellow parakeet who sings with Lillian.
            [1] => Cello is a yellow Lillian.
            [2] => Cello likes Lillian and kittens.
            [3] => Lillian likes Cello and dogs.
        )

)
```

---

If you absolutly need to match sentences where the string Cello appears before Lillian, then you use an expression like this. Here I've simply moved a single close parentheses.

`(?:(?<=\.)\s+|^)((?=(?:(?!\.(?:\s|$)).)*?\b[Cc]ello(?=\s|\.|$)(?=(?:(?!\.(?:\s|$)).)*?\b[Ll]illian(?=\s|\.|$))).*?\.(?=\s|$))`

[image]

Input text

```
Cello is a yellow parakeet who sings with Lillian. Toby is a clown who doesn't sing. Willy is a Wonka. Cello is a yellow Lillian.
Cello likes Lillian and kittens.
Lillian likes Cello and dogs.  Cello has no friends. And Lillian also hasn't met anyone.
```

Output for capture group 1

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Cello is a yellow parakeet who sings with Lillian.
        [1] => Cello is a yellow Lillian.
        [2] => Cello likes Lillian and kittens.
    )
```

Comment: It helps, but the regex yields the following error code: "sre_constants.error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern" Do you by chance know how I can resolve the problem? I would be grateful for any advice you can lend.

Comment: Ok this is a common problem with some lanugage's implementation of regex. Give me a few and I'll post an update.

Comment: Thank you! I would be most grateful if you could help me resolve this question.

Comment: I replaced the `(?<=\s|^)` with `\b` although this isn't as resilient it should do the job.

Comment: Excellent! The script works perfectly for the sample. I have one last question, though: If I wanted to find all instances in which <emotion> and <LOCATION> appear inside the same sentence of an xml file, do you know how I could modify the expression to find these instances and then print them to a unique line? (If you're too busy to respond, I of course understand. If you could modify the code, though, I will forever be in your debt.)

Comment: Now that sounds confusing, I would probably be best to open a new question (they're free) and there include some samples of input and output.